# Style random post ID

Tags: css

How can I style a random post ID in css?

Example:

```
article#post-1825 {padding:10px;}
```

I want to style this for every post `ID` (1825, 1826, 2202, etc.).

Comment: can you use scss?

Comment: Are all of the post-xxx using `article` tag and nothing else uses them? should be targeted with a class if possible

Comment: "I want to style this for every post ID" Every post ID? Or a single random instance of post ID? You can select everything beginning with `#post-` with CSS, but selecting "randomly" isn't possible.

Comment: use [id^=post-]{//your css}